# how to secure message bus queue from being altered

Tags: azure

let's say you have even driven architecture, you send a message to a queue and another service will pick it up, how would you secure that message?because if someone gets access to the queue can change that message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could encrypt it with the public key of a trusted receiver. Then only the trusted receiver, which holds the corresponding private key, would be able to alter the message and verify it has not been altered.